# Firebase Realtime Database SSL encryption overhead

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I’m using the realtime database for my Flutter app.

I’ve red on the Firebase website the db uses SSL encryption overhead. ~ 3.5kb

My app uses multiple listeners and does a lot of update operations. ~ 3 listeners and 50 updates per user session

Do I have to ‘pay’ 3.5kb with every operation?

Or is the ssl connection only once when the app is launched?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacted firebase support about this:

> "The Admin SDK for Node uses a socket to connect to the Firebase
> database. It does not use the REST API. Bandwidth while negotiating
> the HTTPS/WebSocket connection is billable traffic here too. The
> building of this connection from Cloud Functions to the Database
> happens when a new container is created. This can be upon the first
> deployment of the project's functions, after a period of inactivity,
> or when the Cloud Functions needs to be scaled-up due to high
> activity."

Comment: Do you know if this applies to the REST API or for the JavaScript SDK's realtime listeners? I have the exact same question.